# No 'dotnet' Path Set Error pop-up in Eclipse

Tags: c#, eclipse, unity-game-engine, .net-core, eclipse-plugin

I downloaded Eclipse aCute for C# and .NET Core from the Eclipse marketplace to add scripts to Unity. Right after that was done, whenever Eclipse starts up I get a popup that says No 'dotnet' Path Set for .NET core.
[image: Here is the screenshot]

The error comes up every time I run Eclipse so it is basically unusable for me now.

Anyone knows how to fix this? I just need the Eclipse app to work normally again. Perhaps some way to delete the Eclipse aCute for C# and .NET Core download?

No actions can be done and the pop-up can't be resolved or closed. If you close the pop-up it comes back up. Eclipse itself can't be closed except from the task manager.

Comment: I would say to you that just supporting c# is possibly not enough - it does need to support unity even if you sus out how to get the c# happy

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with unity so far. It's the eclipse marketplace download Eclipse aCute for C# and .NET Core itself that broke Eclipse. But thanks for answering.

Comment: no i know but what i mean is, i think you're wasting your time getting it working if you want to use it with unity

Comment: Ah nope actually I want it to work because I use it to code in java. This C# download was just a trial and it broke the app. I just need the app itself to work. Is there a way to revert the download or delete it from a folder or something similar to that just to get Eclipse itself to work again? I don't want to use it with unity anymore.

Comment: as I said "if you want to use it with unity" .. :D

Comment: Does the Open Preferences button not work?

Comment: @nitind nope it just opens the window in the background as you can see in the screenshot and I can't interact with it because of the pop-up coming back again every time I click any option.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can fix this issue by deleting my workspace and creating a new one. This allowed to run Eclipse without the immediate unescapable pop-up. Then I went to preferences and added the path. That worked.